# Warning when calling IsPointerOverGameObject after updating Unity; is there an alternative?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an `InputAction` callback where I am recording the position where the player clicks the screen, but **only** if the click is not over a UI element.  Here's my code

```
private void OnPress(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        this.pressPosition = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
    }
}
```

This has been working correctly.  However, I recently updated my version of Unity, and now I'm getting this warning every time I click somewhere in my game:

```
Calling IsPointerOverGameObject() from within event processing (such as from InputAction callbacks) 
will not work as expected; it will query UI state from the last frame
```

According to the [changelog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/changelog/CHANGELOG.html#110-pre6---2021-08-23), this warning was added with an update to the input system.

Is there a way to figure out whether the mouse was over the UI when the player clicks the screen without getting this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how I solved it was by moving just that piece of logic to an Unity's Update function:

```
private void Update()
{
  if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
  {
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(PointerInputModule.kMouseLeftId))
      // was pressed on GUI
    else
      // was pressed outside GUI
  }
}
```

You can still keep using the inputsystem, i.e. when cancelled:

```
private void OnPress(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
  if (context.canceled)
    // Left mouse is no longer pressed. You can do something within the input system notification.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private bool pressControl = false;
 private void Update()
 {
    if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
        pressControl =!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(PointerInputModule.kMouseLeftId);
 }

 void selector(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
 {
    if (!pressControl) return;
    pressControl = false;

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(mausePositionEvent.ReadValue<Vector2>().x, mausePositionEvent.ReadValue<Vector2>().y, 0);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(position);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) return;
 }
```